# String Variable inside Single Quotes in Another String Variable Not Expanding - VBA

Tags: vba, string, variables

I'm trying to build quite a complicated URL String in VBA and I'm having troule escaping everything correctly. I managed to get the URL to work, but now I'm trying to "variablize" the importart parts and can't understand the issue (VBA doesn't exactly give detailed errors either).

Here is a working and non-working example URL:

```
Dim URL As STring, Client As String
Client = "AClientName"
URL = "http://URL?filter={'mode':'cli','client':'AClientName'}" ' This Works
URL = "http://URL?filter={'mode':'cli','client':' & CLIENT & '}" ' This Fails to Open
```

Comment: ```"http://URL?filter={'mode':'cli','client':'" & client & "'}"``` you need to escape the string and concatenate

Comment: The question is closed as a duplicate, I can't write an answer. That's the gist of it though, I usually ```debug.print``` to see the output and make sure all the variables are properly escaped when I have a larger one to do.

Comment: I reopened the question as it seems like the issue is more around missing the `"` as pointed out in the first comment. Perhaps not a duplicate, but probably just a typo.

Comment: @Warcupine feel free to answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing the a close and open quote around the variable.

If you `debug.print`, you can see that it's interpreting your `&` and `Client` as just another part of the string instead of concatenating it as a variable.

In:

```
Debug.Print "http://URL?filter={'mode':'cli','client':'AClientName'}"
```

Out:

```
http://URL?filter={'mode':'cli','client':'AClientName'}
```

This works because there's no escaping the string or concatenation needed.

---

You can see here that `& CLIENT &` are part of the string.

In:

```
Debug.Print "http://URL?filter={'mode':'cli','client':' & CLIENT & '}"
```

Out:

`http://URL?filter={'mode':'cli','client':' & CLIENT & '}`

---

To get the proper string with the variable use this.

In:

```
Debug.Print "http://URL?filter={'mode':'cli','client':'" & Client & "'}"
```

Out:

```
http://URL?filter={'mode':'cli','client':'AClientName'}
```